# Sincronize databases with git deployment

Tags: mysql, database, git, deployment

So I own a VPS server running CentOS, and decided to use git for deployment. Man! That's fun. Push, done!
I'm really happier than i was with the old ftp approach.

But I wish I could go further, today it deploys automagically all my files, but it doesn't even touch my db. And if I change it in the mods, I have to update it manually. So i was thinking about using some git hooks to do this also automatically.

By now I'm using one git hook at the server, it's a post-receive hook and basically copies files to the production directory when pushed to master.

The prerequisites for the DB deployment are:

1. It needs to go both ways, if i pull from db, and it's different from my local it should update my local db.
2. It should be based on modifications and patchs and not the dump of the whole db, this way i can work with the team without compromising other guys work.

I was thinking about keeping a db.sql on the version control, and make a script to analyze it on post-receive (on server) and post-merge(on local), so it can take the mods and apply, and i would keep a database of which mods were applied already (the script should run in both, client and server).

Any of you guys have already done something similar to this? What would you recommend?

Thank you very much already,

Comment: Synchronize the data? Or synchronize the structure? Both? (I don't believe it matters what your answer is.  Databases are inherently different than file systems.  Git (any SCM) manages file versions and allows you to "rollback".  You cannot rollback a DROP column - the data is gone.  You cannot rollback a UPDATE foo SET bar='foofoo')

Comment: The structure mainly. Your comment sure makes a lot of sense and i couldn't agree more with you. But even if i can't rollback with git, it would already makes my life easier in the normal workflow. I could also have a db-full.sql that dumps the whole data on hooks also, so i could apply it when needed.
Any ideas on possible solutions for the problem? It doesn't have to be a git solution, i'll use git more like a trigger for when to sync the db. Thanks!

Comment: We tried this a few times, always with the best intentions, but never with the ideal results. We found the best investment of time was to put the DDL of the individual change (CREATE, DROP, ALTER), in order for us to track changes/ features from a development environment to production (and for code reviews).  We always relied on a backup if we really needed to recreate the entire database though. I am watching your question for other SO contributors to add their feedback.

Comment: Ok, and I'll let you know if find any solutions =) Thanks AgRizzo!